# how to run cocos2d-iphone test projects

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.6

I have downloaded and installed xcode 4.6.3 and also installed cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1.
when I create new cocos2d project and run it, it shows helloworld but when I try to open cocos2d big project containing tests and try to run any test I get compiling errors I don't know what is the problem and how to fix it.

please help me fix this problem and run the tests.

[image]

Comment: Get cocos2d 2.0 or at least 1.1. The 1.0 version is not up to date with Xcode & iOS SDK updates.

Comment: Not handled in switch? Add default case, maybe that helps.

Comment: I am afraid of the possibility that, may be if I install latest version of cocos2d, my older project would not run.. will it happen ?

Comment: @Saifee just make sure you make a backup before trying the latest version.  Or better yet you are using version control right?

Comment: @RobSegal I just deleted cocos2d 1.0.1 and installed the latest version, and now all the tests are working fine..